# Access to child component reference for Angular @ViewChildren

Tags: angular, viewchildren

I'm creating a number of ModuleItemComponents using the following Angular markup:

```
<div #moduleItems *ngFor="let module of seriesItem.modules; let i = index">
    <app-module-item [videoModule]="module" ></app-module-item>    
</div>
```

and the following code lives in the corresponding .ts file:

```
  @ViewChildren('moduleItems') moduleItems;
```

I'm using code in the ngAfterViewInit event to try and get a reference to each ModuleItemComponent:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   let items: [];
   items = this.moduleItems.map((m) => m.nativeElement.firstChild);
   items.forEach((m) => {
     const thisModule = (m as ModuleItemComponent);
     thisModule.onSelectionMade.subscribe((result: VideoModule) => {
       this.deselectOthers(result);
     });
   });
 }
```

However, I get an error at the ".subscribe" line because the type of thisModule is app-module-item, not ModuleItemComponent.

[image]

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong - just not sure how to do this right. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need put the variable reference in the `<app-module-item>`

```
<app-module-item #moduleItems ...>
```

But in this case, you can use the own name of the class and forget the variable reference

```
@ViewChildren(ModuleItemComponent) moduleItems:QueryList<ModuleItemComponent>
```

And you can do

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{
 
   this.moduleItems.forEach(item=>{
        ..item is a ModuleItemComponent.. 
        ..you has access to all his properties..
        ..e.g. item.onSelectionMade.subscribe(....)
    })
}
```

See that the name of the class is not between quotes -I supose the name of the class is ModuleItemComponent, else change for the name of the class-